# GAM concurvity measures greater than 1

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gamlss, concurvity

I am currently using a gam modelling approach to describe the effects of several variables (es_sum, nat_sum, sect_sum, and prop_spec) on another variable (btwn). Each of es_sum, nat_sum, sect_sum, and prop_spec vary with a further factor, bin_deg (4 levels). I've used a factor smooth for each term to address this:

```
Bgam <-  mgcv::gam(btwn~ 
         s(es_sum, bin_deg, bs="fs",  k=9) + 
         s(nat_sum, bin_deg, bs="fs", k=8) +
         s(sect_sum, bin_deg, bs="fs", k=7) +
         s(prop_spec,bin_deg, bs="fs"),
         data=nz_dat, 
       method="REML", 
       family=tw,
       select=TRUE) #double penalty approach
```

There is a degree of concurvity (quite a bit!) between these smooths (which to me makes sense, as each varies by the level of bin_deg. In a different approach I'm using GAMLSS (family=gaulss) to deal with residual variance varying with each level of bin_deg, but that's a separate issue. What I'm interested in here is concurvity, which for many smoothers in my model Bgam, is greater than 1. Here's the output of concurvity():

```
concurvity(Bgam, full=TRUE)
         para s(es_sum,bin_deg) s(nat_sum,bin_deg) s(sect_sum,bin_deg) s(prop_spec,bin_deg)
worst       1      3.943891e+32       3.304069e+32        1.070997e+31            1.0000000
observed    1      8.378792e-01       4.576376e+00        5.610474e-01            0.6003964
estimate    1      9.896317e-01       9.778687e-01        9.632215e-01            0.8870775
```

Clearly I need to deal with this (I will!), but more fundamentally I'm wondering if anyone could explain how it is possible to get concurvity values >1?

Comment: The values aren't supposed to be >1 so there is clearly some bug or issue here. I suggest you email Simon Wood with this example so he can see what's happening and fix it. The summary suggests most of the smooths are almost entirely unidentifiable, which suggests bigger problems than just concurvity; all these are sums of something, are those somethings related in some way?

Comment: Thanks @GavinSimpson - appreciate the feedback. I'll email Simon Wood. Agree - there are issues with the dataset itself - the sums are equivalent to 'richness' or 'cumulative species', but are associated with individuals and their network. I.e. how many nationalities you are connected to, or sectors. These all depend to some degree, but not entirely on the number of connections you have. I'm working on solving this, but it's turning into a StackOverflow question! Thanks for help with this!

Comment: Hi @RMiller (and @GavinSimpson), did you ever email Simon Wood, and if so, could you perhaps share his response? I am also having occasional concurvity values slightly above 1 (e.g. 1.01) in the case of overall concurvity. (I've also found that for the pairwise concurvity analyses the matrices are sometimes not symmetric (i.e. different value for x-y concurvity compared to y-x concurvity), which I don't understand, and wonder if that is related to the above issue).

Comment: @Jade only one of the metrics is supposed to be symmetric (worst) the others can by asymmetric. See `?concurvity`.

Comment: @Gavin the asymmetry I got was for worst concurvity. Note (wbgt_max, lag) vs (time) and vv:
```r     
                                  para      s(time) te(wbgt_max,lag) te(precip_daily_total,lag)

para                       1.000000e+00 6.033833e-17       0.01386905                  0.6677235
s(time)                    6.033871e-17 1.000000e+00       0.92307765                 0.7784443
te(wbgt_max,lag)   7.989766e-03 9.097163e-01       1.00000000                  0.5898419
te(precip_daily_total,lag) 6.677235e-01 7.784443e-01       0.62523872         1.0000000
```

Comment: Sorry for the jumbled up results. Can't seem to get decently formatted output in comments. Anyway, concurvity for (wbgt_max, lag) vs (time) is 9.097163e-01, whereas (time) vs (wbgt_max, lag) is 0.92307765. The difference is small, and for my purposes it does not matter (concurvity in my GAMs is very high, which is my main headache, and a difference of 0.01 does not matter), but I just found it odd.